# Creating a slingshot/ bow and arrow with Swift/Spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a bow and arrow style slingshot where there is a line that has a node on it, and when you touch and drag back the node the string bends back with it as a bow would, and when the touch is released the ball is propelled forward.

From what I've seen, the only way to make a rope is to create a ton of little segments and give them a pin joint. I need for the arrow to say on the string but also for it to be able to slide up and down the string. I can't give the arrow and bow a joint because the arrow would just get stuck on one of the sections.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this, or is this really quite the monster?

Thanks

Comment: This resource may be helpful: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_8_Swift_Sprite_Kit_Level_Editor_Game_Tutorial